# android : notification when a new row is created

Tags: android, notifications

as the title says I want to create an app that whenever a new row is being created on a remote database,a notification message is displayed on the user's screen.Is it possible to achieve that by using a trigger and SQL queries? If there is another way can you please suggest any tutorials or ideas on how to do that?Any help would be really appreciated.

P.S : I am really sorry for this general question but i can't find anything solid anywhere else

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

It will do exactly what you want.

In simple turns it will work like this: Once the right event triggers on your server, it sends a request to google cloud to notify your users of the event. BroadcastReceivers in your app will get notified by google and you can process the event any way you want it.

P.S. google for some tutorials for GCM, its not that hard to implement at all.